# What is the difference between #cmakedefine and #define when used within the context of an input file to configure_file?

Tags: cmake

### Background

I'm running through the [CMake tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/A%20Basic%20Starting%20Point.html) and found the solution for [TODO #10](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/A%20Basic%20Starting%20Point.html#tutorialconfig-h-in), i.e:

#### TutorialConfig.h.in

```
#define Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR @Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR@
#define Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR @Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR@
```

seems to conflict with the manual for the [`configure_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html#command:configure_file) command

> configure_file( 
> [NO_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS | USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS |
> FILE_PERMISSIONS ...]
> [COPYONLY] [ESCAPE_QUOTES] [@ONLY]
> [NEWLINE_STYLE [UNIX|DOS|WIN32|LF|CRLF] ])
>
> Copies an  file to an  file and substitutes variable
> values referenced as @VAR@ or ${VAR} in the input file content. Each
> variable reference will be replaced with the current value of the
> variable, or the empty string if the variable is not defined.
> Furthermore, input lines of the form
>
> #cmakedefine VAR ...
>
> will be replaced with either
>
> #define VAR ...
>
> or
>
> /* #undef VAR */
>
> depending on whether VAR is set in CMake to any value not considered a
> false constant by the if() command. The "..." content on the line
> after the variable name, if any, is processed as above.

in that the `#cmakedefine` preprocessor directive should be used in the input file an turned into a `#define` directive in the output file rather than what is done in the solution (using the `#define` directive in the input file). I tried using the `#cmakedefine` directive before looking at the solution and it resulted in an undefined _VERSION_MINOR i.e. here is the generated header file:

#### TutorialConfig.h

```
#define Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR 1                                                                                                            
/* #undef Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR */
```

whereas when I use the `#define` directive within the input file (TutorialConfig.h.in), both `Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR` and `Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR` are defined in the generated header file. i.e.

#### TutorialConfig.h

```
#define Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR 1                                                                                                            
#define Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR 0
```

So what is the difference here and why would one properly grab the defined `Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR` and another not? Is there specific documentation regarding the `#cmakedefine` and `#cmakedefine01` directives other than what is shown in the [`configure_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html#command:configure_file) documentation?

Based on a comment received highlighting the following text from the `configure_file` documentation:

> "[...] depending on whether VAR is set in CMake to any value not considered a false constant by the if() command".

I'm wondering if the only difference between using the `#cmakedefine` and `#define` directives is just that the `#cmakedefine` one goes through an `if()` statement and thus any value of `0` would result in the output header file showing an undefined variable rather than a string of `0` as intended.

- cmake version 3.22.1

### Minimal Working Example

A full working minimal example below or alternatively can be found [here](https://github.com/topherbuckley/CMake/tree/minimalExample/Help/guide/tutorial/Step1):

#### tutorial.cxx

```cpp
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "TutorialConfig.h"

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Version: " << Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR << "." << Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

#### TutorialConfig.h.in

```cpp
#define Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR @Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR@
#define Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR @Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR@
```

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(Tutorial
    VERSION 1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

configure_file(TutorialConfig.h.in 
    TutorialConfig.h
    @ONLY)

add_executable(Tutorial
    tutorial.cxx)

target_include_directories(Tutorial 
    PUBLIC
    ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
```

### Steps to reproduce this:

1. From the directory containing the above 3 files (e.g. `Step1`) make a build directory with `mkdir build`
2. `cd build`
3. `cmake ..`
4. `make`
5. `./Tutorial` and note it prints Version: 1.0 as expected
6. `cd ..`
7. Change the `#define` directives in `TutorialConfig.h.in` to `#cmakedefine`, i.e.

   TutorialConfig.h.in:

   ```cpp
   #cmakedefine Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR @Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR@
   #cmakedefine Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR @Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR@
   ```
8. repeat steps 2-4 and note the compile error:

   ```
   Step1/tutorial.cxx:8:64: error: ‘Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR’ was not declared in this scope; did
    you mean ‘Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR’?                                                                                                         
       8 |   std::cout << "Version: " << Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR << "." << Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR << std::endl;                                 
         |                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                               
         |                                                                Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR
   ```

Comment: What's the problem? `VERSION_MINOR` is 0, that is considered `false` and (according to the link you posted): "[...] depending on whether VAR is set in CMake to any value not considered a false constant by the if() command". So it works as documented, or doesn't it?

Comment: Hmm, so maybe the #cmakedefine directive is interpreting 0 differently than #define? The problem is that if I were to use the #cmakedefine directive, the `Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR` will be undefined, when in fact it should be defined, to be zero.

Comment: When still in doubt, with three lines of CMake and three lines of C++ code, you can test it out. It's a trivial experiment and you will see exactly what happens.

Comment: @Friedrich I did test it, which is what led to creating this question. I wanted to know more about the difference from what I could just anecdotally test. What I was really looking for lies [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/9b07b57c01427fb3abd1920950914dbb89122e91/Source/cmMakefile.cxx#L3861-L3886), which is the definitive difference.

Answer (score 1):

As Friedrich already mentioned in the comments, CMake is doing exactly what it's documented to do.

You wrote:

```
project(Tutorial
    VERSION 1.0)
```

, so in the following

```
#cmakedefine Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR @Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR@
```

, for the first "`Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR`", CMake looks at what the value of that CMake variable is, and sees that it is a value considered false by [the `if()` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#command:if). Yes- `Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR` is a CMake variable. See [the `<PROJECT_NAME>_VERSION_MINOR` docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT-NAME_VERSION_MINOR.html). The specific docs that say `0` is considered as a falsy value in the `if()` command docs is [under the "basic expressions" section](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#basic-expressions):

> False if the constant is `0`, `OFF`, `NO`, `FALSE`, `N`, `IGNORE`, `NOTFOUND`, the empty string, or ends in the suffix `-NOTFOUND`. Named boolean constants are case-insensitive.

And as the documentation you linked states, `#cmakedefine VAR ...` is replaced with `/* #undef VAR */` when "*`VAR` is set in CMake to any value considered a false constant by the `if()` command.*"

---

> seems to conflict with the manual for the configure_file command [...] in that the #cmakedefine preprocessor directive should be used in the input file an turned into a `#define` directive in the output file rather than what is done in the solution (using the #define directive in the input file)

uhh no. The tutorial just uses the approach that will actually work here. This kind of scenario where you want to create a macro definition with the same name as a CMake variable where the CMake variable might be a CMake-falsy value is the weakness scenario of `#cmakedefine` that one can avoid by instead using `#define` and `configure_file`'s variable substitution facilities- namely `@VAR@` and `${VAR}`.

There's nothing special about `#define` with respect to `configure_file`. It just treats it like any other text. `#cmakedefine`, `#cmakedefine01` and variable substitution with `@VAR@` and `${VAR}` are the only things `configure_file` does special things for.

Since you expressed interest in where to find the source code for this: [the source file you linked](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/9b07b57c01427fb3abd1920950914dbb89122e91/Source/cmMakefile.cxx#L3861-L3886) is just a wrapper for parsing the command from the CMake script and calling the actual business logic. See the `.GetMakefile().ConfigureFile()` call. Trace that to `cmMakefile.cxx`'s `cmMakefile::ConfigureFile`, and that to `cmMakefile::ConfigureString` to `cmValue.h`'s `cmIsOff`, to `cmValue.cxx`'s `cmValue::IsOff`.

Comment: It doesn't have to acually use `if()`. It's just using the _same logic_ as `if()` to determine if a CMake variable is falsy to decide whether or not to output `/* #undef VAR */`. There's nothing special about `#define` with respect to `configure_file`. It just treats it like any other text. `#cmakedefine`, `#cmakedefine01` and variable substitution with `@VAR@` and `${VAR}` are the only things `configure_file` does special things for.

Comment: @topher217 The first two sentences of the docs: "_Copy a file to another location and modify its contents._" and "_Copies an `<input>` file to an `<output>` file and substitutes variable values referenced as `@VAR@` or `${VAR}` in the input file content._". As I've said already, `#define` is not interpreted specially by `configure_file`. So it just gets copied from the input file to the output.

Comment: There might have been some confusion regarding `#define` vs. `#cmakedefine`. The first is a *preprocessor directive* and evaluated by the C++ preprocessor. It's part of the language standard. In contrast, `#cmakedefine` is something the guys from CMake came up with. It's evaluated by CMake's `configure_file` command and treated as described in this answer.